# Custom counters from dataflow in the Stackdriver monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, stackdriver

How can I view the custom counters defined in my dataflow job to the stackdriver monitoring.

As the google documents says the any custom counters defines in the dataflow will be reported as the custom metrics in the stackdriver.

But I cant see any custom metrics in the Stackdriver Metrics Explorer page when I am filtering it in the "Find resource type and metric" box.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? How did you define your custom counters? Have you looked at [this page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stackdriver-monitoring)?

Comment: I am using dataflow sdk  1.9, I defined the custom counter using Aggregator in DoFn, and I also gone through that page, in dataflow UI I can see the Custom counter, but not in the stackdriver.

Comment: Could you share the job ID for which you expected the aggregator to show up in Stackdriver?

Comment: 2017-05-18_01_55_40-1851465512781927465

Comment: In order for Dataflow to report or for you to consume custom metrics through Stackdriver, the project needs to have Stackdriver Premium enabled.  Is the project used to execute the job configured for Stackdriver Premium?

Comment: No, we are using Basic tire, I get it now , thank you for your suggestion...